# Cannot assign LinkedList to List, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm using Java in Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.5 (JDK Compliance level 5.0) with and I'm getting very strange compilation problems that I wasn't getting before (and I don't think I've updated my compiler or Eclipse, but maybe an update was installed that I wasn't aware of). For example if I have the following line in my code:

```
List foo = new LinkedList();
```

I get a warning that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList to List
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would check which `List` has been imported by Eclipse for you.  If it is a GUI `java.awt.List`, it is not the `java.util.List` interface that `LinkedList` implements and would therefore cause that compile-time error.